# Sorting arraylist of objects on a string date property

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have an `Arraylist` of `MyObject` which have a date property `busDt` but it is as a `String`.

I want to sort my `Arraylist` on the date.

I wrote the following code:

```
Collections.sort(myObjectList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
          public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {                  
              SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
              try {
                return sdf.parse(o1.getBusDt()).compareTo(sdf.parse(o2.getBusDt()));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            }
          }
        });
```

Is my code correct ? Any inputs would be a great help!

Thanks for reading!

Comment: If you just want a code review, codereview.stackexchange.com may be more suitable. Otherwise, does your code work for you? Are you sure that you want to consider two elements equal if either of them as an unparsable date? (Hint: that will break the `compareTo` contract.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The answer you marked is having property as java.util.Date.  I want to confirm if my usage of SimpleDateFormat with its try catch on parse is correct or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Exactly. So if I remove "return 0" from catch block, it will show error that a return statement is mandatory. What should I do for that case ? That is my confusion and the reason for posting this question.

Comment: It would make more sense if the field of `MyObject` was a `Date` rather than a `String`. Then you could just compare the `Date` objects.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: Sorry. Won't be able to modify that.

Comment: Ok, well do you want the dates that can't be parsed to be at the beginning or the end of the list?

Comment: @PaulBoddington: At the end

Comment: In that case, there are 4 cases. (1) o1 and o2 both unparsable: return 0. (2) o1 unparseable, o2 parsable: return 1, (3) o1 parsable, o2 unparsable: return -1 (4) both parsable: compare dates. If you don't do it this way `Collections.sort` can throw an exception if it detects an illegal `Comparator`.